# When should we add aes() ? The first code is giving error while the other isn't

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

**Code giving error:**
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(shape = 1, size = 4))

**Code Not giving error:**
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(shape = 1, size = 4)

Comment: I previously answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817622/11374827).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of timing.  It's a question of default behaviour.

The actual error message is

```
Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
```

So in the first example, because `shape` is inside the call to `aes()`, it is defining a scale.  `1` is regarded not as a constant but as a continuous variable.

In the second example, because shape is *outside* the call to `aes()`, it does not define a scale and therefore the error does not occur.

A variation of the first example which does not produce an error is

```
gplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(1), size = 4))
```

because the call to `as.factor()` means that `1` is no longer regarded as continuous.